# xargs not working

Tags: bash, shell, xargs, ack

I want all the lines with assert_equal and without amazon.

I tried following but it is not working.

```
ack assert_equal | xargs ack -v amazon
```

Comment: @DigitalRoss, ack is a find and grep utility. see also http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: This should probably be migrated to super user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need xargs:

```
ack assert_equal | ack -v amazon
```

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a couple of problems with your command.  In the first part:

> ack assert_equal

you do not provide a filename, so `ack` has nothing to process.  In the second part:

> xargs ack -v amazon

you are using `xargs` to provide the results from the initial `ack` as command-line arguments to the second `ack`, which is probably not what you intended.  `ack` is already designed to accept data on standard input, so you do not need to use `xargs` at all.

Here is a statement that should work better:

> ack assert_equal filename | ack -v amazon

or, if you are getting the output from another command, something like:

> my_command | ack assert_equal | ack -v amazon

Comment: The `ack` available from betterthangrep.com (as mentioned by Dave Bacher above) will not return any data when run with a single argument (at least on my machine).  Another `ack` program, the Kanji code converter, will output any text file provided as-is, but it does not take a -v argument so I'm guessing that's not it.  Is there a third `ack` you might be using?

Comment: ack does not need a filename to search.  It only needs a search pattern.  It assumes it wants to search the entire tree down, starting with the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

`ack` is not a standard tool in *nix. since you have it, its ok. But if you are on a *nix system which doesn't have it, here's how you can do it

```
awk '/assert_equal/&&!/amazon/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

this snippet should give you an idea as to what you need to do. The magic is in the -print0 option. Not a direct solution; i'm feeling lazy.

```
ack -f --print0 --php -G 'scripts' --invert-file-match|xargs -0 ls -l
```